# Fill background color bottom to top: slight error

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have used a transition to fill background color from bottom to top. The animation works absolutely fine on the snippets here and also on codepen.io (https://codepen.io/mohits0631/pen/pojBmOa) but there is a colored line under the text on my website. Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? I am adding a screenshot of it here

[image]

following is my code:

```css
.btn-text:link,
.btn-text:visited{
    color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .3rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, green 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-position: top;
    transition: background-position 0.9s ease-out;
}
.btn-text:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn-text">Learn More &rarr;</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried the property text-decoration:none without its pseudo-element?

Comment: add it to ur css "text-decoration: none".

Comment: I tried using the text-decoration:none without its pseudo-element, but it still doesnt work

Comment: If you can't reproduce it perhaps provide a link to show us the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is one way of doing this, but you can also relatively position the link and apply a `:after` pseudo-selector to that link, to then absolutely position that to the bottom, with initially a height set to 0, to then fill that up on hover. Think of something like this:

```
.link { 
  position: relative; 
}
.link:after { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute; 
  bottom:0; 
  left:0; 
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: height 0.3s linear;
}
.link:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Protip: it's actually bad practice to transition anything that is not `opacity` or `transform`, but there are ways to do that in these ways too, like with `scaleY` in conjunction with a `transform-origin` set to bottom and an initial height to 100%, but the first option should be just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your site's template probably has some text-decoration you need to override.

In your CSS, you are only applying text-decoration:none to the class when a pseudo-element applies. But you want to apply text-decoration:none to all states of that class. Try this:

```
.btn-text{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Depending on the template, you also might have to add !important.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I messed around with the code and there seems to be some problem with the linear-gradient property because the background-color moves a little bit more upwards than it is supposed to

Comment: Can you share the styles for that element that are showing up in your browser's inspector tool? If you use Firefox, that would be preferred.